# how to get value of ui slider handle in respective div

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery ui slider, I have two handle, what I all want is to get handle value in respective div for example. I want to update handle one value in "handle1" div and handle 2 value in "handle2" div. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LWxJP/)

```
$("#slider").slider({values:[0,100],
slide: function(event, ui){
//alert(ui.handle)
}              
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ui` argument of [slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) event has the values array, which will gives the values of handles, you can use it

```
$("#slider").slider({
    values: [0, 100],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $('.handle1').text(ui.values[0]);
        $('.handle2').text(ui.values[1]);
    }    
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SjR6k/)

Comment: Thank arun it is working fine, One more thing i want to know. How can we get current active handle value. Like if we have only one div to show value. I want to append current active handle value in it.http://jsfiddle.net/SjR6k/2/